Category of sheaves of vector spaces on BG
Let $G$ be an affine group scheme over $\mathbb{C}$. I am interested in understanding the differences between different notions of sheaves on the stack $pt/G = BG$. For any algebraic stack $X$ one can consider the lisse-etale topology as in Laumon and Moret-Bailly to define sheaves of vector spaces or quasicoherent sheaves on $X$. If we consider quasicoherent sheaves one can show that $QCoh BG \cong Rep G = \mathcal{O}_{G}-comod$, the category of representations of $G$.
My question is about the category of sheaves of vector spaces (not necessarily quasicoherent) on $BG$. Is there a nice description of this category ?
